# My Mentor trophy won't pop up

Tags: assassins-creed-revelations

I have 7 assassins that have reached the rank of master assassin but I didn't get the trophy. My dens are full so I can't rank anyone else up. What should I do?

Comment: Make sure you assign each of them to a den in the city, *not* in the Mediterranean map. I believe that's one of the pre-requisites for getting the trophy.

Answer (score 2):

All 7 den leaders must be level 15 (with a little assassin logo under their name in the Mediterranean defense menu) to unlock this trophy/achievement.  To get them all to level 15, they must have enough experience, and you must do all of the Master Assassin missions.  The first of each den is unlocked when assigning an assassin as a den leader, but as they gain enough experience to become a Master, a second one will be unlocked.  You can see if these missions are available by looking at the map for black squares with the assassin logo in it.

I think you are confusing assigning den leaders with reaching the rank of master assassin.  Let me know if I am wrong.  If so, it must be a bug.

Comment: I think it's bugged then cause I did everything it said to do I have pics of what I see but I guess there isn't a way to show them

Comment: If you have them saved to your computer you can edit your original post, hit the image icon in the post toolbar and upload them.  I encourage you to do so.

Comment: I am using my Itouch can't get it to work

Comment: Hm. Well what does it say in your Assassin guild challenges? Under the third set of challenges should be: "Train 7 assassin's to level of Master Assassin: x/7" or something like that.  If that says 7/7 then you most definitely have a bug.

Comment: Yeah it says 6/7 there and I've already came to the conclusion that I'll have to replay to get it. I am 2 trophies from reaching platinum

Comment: Two last things to try. With the map open, if you hit RB(probably R2 on PS3, maybe R1) it should show all of your dens.  They're all definitely locked?  You could also try sending a master assassin on mediterranean defense missions with less than a 100% success rate to get him killed and train another to master assassin. Although if you've already done all the unique missions, 5 dot ones might not be able to kill master assassins.

Comment: From what I've tried they can't be killed but yeah all 7 dens are under assassin controll

Comment: Ah sorry then, looks like you have to do a new game.